# Can I add a .js library? how?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have some [code](https://github.com/deepakkumar1984/Math-Expression-Generator) from gitHub I'd like to run in GAS, but it uses a library ([chance.js](http://chancejs.com/)) I don't know how to install.

I have looked at the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries), and tried to follow the steps but I don't have a project key (because nobody's used it in GAS?).

I see that I might be able to call it from my script (?), but I don't even know how to start with that - I am a novice at this.

Is there a simple way to add this library? Can you point me to any resources?

Comment: I have tried downloading the library, copying the code and adding it to a script file within the script. This did not work

Comment: @SpiderPig The addition of the beginning and ending code as shown in the answer below worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the development version of chance.js. Open it and copy the whole text. Then go to your Apps Script editor, create a new script (File/New/Script File) and paste the text into there. Then at the bottom of the chance.js code (but before the closing parenthesis) you need to add `chance = new Chance();`

btw. In Apps Script every single time you start a function manually or through a trigger, all the js code in all js files belonging to the project is being executed and only afterwards is the selected function run. Of course that doesn't mean that the code inside of all the functions is being run.

edit:

Here is a better approach.
Change the start of chance.js from `(function () {` to `Chance = (function () {`. And then change the end from `})();` to

```
    return Chance;
})();

chance = new Chance();
```

Comment: I changed my answer. That way both `Chance` and `chance` should work.